# Why custom dropdown list directive is not working inside ngView?

Tags: jquery, list, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I used [this guide](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/) to create a custom `dropdown list` without `select`(customization of `select` is not supported on all browsers).
This way combine some `CSS` and jQUery. I created a `directive` for this `dropdown list`, everything seems to be working fine with `Angular` until I tried to implement it inside `ng-view`, my rendered `template` simply are not working with my solution(`directive`).

[My code - plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nScqtFkoyY8Sx2y5eUSV?p=preview)  - In my plunk you'd be able to see the working `dropdown list` in index.html and the `dropdown list` which is not working in temp.html(rendered to `ngView`)
Both `dropdown lists` use the same `directive`.

**My index.html:**

```
  <body ng-controller='VotesCtrl'>

    <p>This is working (no ng-view):</p>
    <div dropdown id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
      <i class="arrow"></i>
      <span>{{statuses[0]}}</span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li ng-repeat="status in statuses"><a href="#">{{status}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="content" ng-view></div>  
   </body>
```

**My temp.html which is rendered by router to ng-view:**

```
<p>This is from ng-View, not working:</p>

<div dropdown id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
  <i class="arrow"></i>
  <span>{{statuses[0]}}</span>
  <ul class="dropdown">
        <li ng-repeat="status in statuses"><a href="#">{{status}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**My code(including the `directive`):**

```
// Code goes here


var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);


//router logic
webApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'temp.html',
            controller: 'tempCtrl'
        })

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

//controllers

webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.statuses = ["Approved","Pending","Trash","Spam"];
});


webApp.controller ('tempCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.statuses = ["Approved","Pending","Trash","Spam"];
});
//services



//directive
webApp.directive('dropdown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function() {
          $(function() {

              var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

              $(document).click(function() {
                  // all dropdowns
                  $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
              });

          });

          function DropDown(el) {
              this.dd = el;
              this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
              this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
              this.val = '';
              this.index = -1;
              this.initEvents();
          }
          DropDown.prototype = {
              initEvents : function() {
                  var obj = this;

                  obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                      $(this).toggleClass('active');
                      return false;
                  });

                  obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                      var opt = $(this);
                      obj.val = opt.text();
                      obj.index = opt.index();
                      obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
                  });
              },
              getValue : function() {
                  return this.val;
              },
              getIndex : function() {
                  return this.index;
              }
          } 
        }
    };
});
```

There are, more or less, similar questions for this issues, but they didn't help me much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error: No method "initEvents" on DropDown. The reason for that in Javascript the functions and vars are defined first, then the code executes. So in the `link` function the function `DropDown` is defined, but the code inside `$(function() {...` runs *before* the code that defines `DropDown`'s prototype.

So the first change is to put the `$(function() {...` code *below* the prototype code.

Then you initialize something with id `dd`. There are two things with this id, so jQuery will get confused. There is no reason to do that; use the element argument provided by the link function.

So 2nd change:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    ...
    var dd = new DropDown(elem); // NOT $('#dd')
    ...
 }
```

(Since you are at it, correct or remove the `<div id="dd">` things)

Finally Angular needs to find jQuery in order for `elem` above to have all jQuery methods.

So final change: Include the jQuery `<script>` *above* Angular.

See forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ffltLZit27EGpW13RmRe?p=preview

---

Now having said the above, I think you are not using Angular correctly. I know, I have jQuery background and in the beginning tended to do everything with jQuery. My proposed changes:

- Do not use jQuery events (unless there is a really good reason - not in this case). Use a template for the directive and `ng-click` instead of `$(...).on("click")`. (Remeber, if the jQuery click modifies the model, you will have to use `$scope.$apply()`.)
- The `$(document).click(function() {` part will install N event handlers on the document, one for each select. Only 1 is actually required, so I would place it outside the `link` function. Most probably inside the directive definition function:

  ```
  webApp.directive('dropdown', function() {
      $(document).click(function() {
          ...
      });
      return {
          ...
      };
  });
  ```
- Using `$(function() {...}` is unecessary. The document will have loaded when the directive is applied.

Comment: You plunk is not fully working. The selected option is not becoming the active one

Comment: I managed by following your comments to create something that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/TBrlW2kU5oi0xDkEZPe3?p=preview